# Linking protocol buffers library in XCode

Tags: xcode, linker, protocol-buffers

I want to use Google Protocol Buffers for C++ in XCode.
This is my directory where I have the library: `/Developer/Protobuf`.

What I did inside this directory, is compiled the `.proto` and produced the `.pb.h` & .`pb.cc` files. After this produced the object file:

```
clang++ -arch x86_64 -I./src -I./  -c file.pb.cc
```

Then:

```
ar -r file.pb.a file.pb.o
```

In XCode, in `Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries` I have added `file.pb.a` static library. In `Build Settings -> Header Search Paths` I have added `/Developer/Protobuf/src`. In `Build Settings -> Librabry Search Paths` I have added `/Developer/Protobuf`. In `Build Settings -> User Header Search Paths` I have added also `/Developer/Protobuf/src`.

But when I compiled the project I always get this kind of errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::generated_pool()", referenced from:
      musicbrainz::protobuf_AssignDesc_musicbrainz_2eproto() in musicbrainz.pb.o
  "google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::InternalAddGeneratedFile(void const*, int)", referenced from:
      musicbrainz::protobuf_AddDesc_musicbrainz_2eproto() in musicbrainz.pb.o
  "google::protobuf::MessageFactory::generated_factory()", referenced from:
      musicbrainz::protobuf_AssignDesc_musicbrainz_2eproto() in musicbrainz.pb.o
  "google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedFile(char const*, void (*)(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&))", referenced from:
      musicbrainz::protobuf_AddDesc_musicbrainz_2eproto() in musicbrainz.pb.o
.................................................................................
```

Maybe I am not creating the static library correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to compile the Protocol Buffers static libraries using their makefiles, and then, link in the static libraries into your project. You should not be pulling in their source code into your Xcode project.

When linking the libraries into my project, I had the same 'undefined symbols' errors as you. Based on comment #19 [in this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/protobuf/oEQVT8pdr5I/HWWdqgbvADUJ), running the following commands when building the Protocol Buffers libraries will make them go away.

```
$ ./configure CC=clang CXX="clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" CXXFLAGS="-O3" --disable-shared
$ make
```

Comment: Still getting the same error on mac for protobuf-2.4.1